# Exact booting process of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

what is the exact booting process of Ubuntu ( Linux). I mean what files it will load and what status it will verify before start booting  & in the booting how it will move.

could some one explain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the boot process goes through the BIOS > Master Boot Record (MBR) > GRUB > kernel > init > run level. These two articles explain briefly and in detail:

1. [6 Stages of Linux Boot Process](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/)
2. [Inside the Linux Boot Process](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/)